# How can I hard-kill a pipeline job without access to console?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job that started spamming it's console very rapidly (gigabytes per minute). What's a good way to kill/stop it?
Pressing the red "x" will not stop it, and I can't see the prompt in the console as the console is so large that it won't be displayed properly.

As pipelines survive a service restart, even that did not help.

Comment: You could try one of the many techniques mentionned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456592/how-to-stop-an-unstoppable-zombie-job-on-jenkins-without-restarting-the-server).

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked that there are new options available in the left build menu after the initial abort request, like "abort all steps", and "force kill" (can't recall the exact link text).