# Trouble stopping jenkins pipeline jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Trouble aborting pipeline jobs

We recently converted some of our jobs over to pipeline jobs (specifically, multibranch pipeline jobs), and since we did so, stopping builds has become much more problematic.

Back when they were freestyle jobs, the builds would immediately stop when we clicked the red X next to a build.

But when we do that in a pipeline job, often it won't stop.  In the console output, we'll get something like this:

```
Aborted by [USERNAME]
Sending interrupt signal to process
Click here to forcibly terminate running steps
```

We have to click that link in the third line, and then it often leaves mercurial repositories in a bad state.

Why did stopping builds work fine with freestyle jobs, but not with Pipeline jobs, and is there any way to get them working well with Pipeline jobs?

Comment: Could you please tell which Jenkins version you are using? We had similar problems with older versions of the Pipeline Plugin, but since we updated, the cancel is working well. We sometimes still have problems that the pipeline is not stopped immediently, in this case, we simply hit the red x 4 or 5 times, then, it gets stopped :-)

Comment: We are using version 2.19.4

Comment: This question has a good answer to how to stop the multi branch pipeline jobs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456592/how-to-stop-an-unstoppable-zombie-job-on-jenkins-without-restarting-the-server