# How to kill the hung job that is running on jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins

Need help regarding kill the hung job that is running on Jenkins slave. As the job is hung we cannot able to stop from Jenkins GUI and unable to find any PID (by login to the server) as the Slave.jar itself a process that is running on a slave server.Can anyone help me to kill the particular hung Job?

Note : Need not to do restart of slave , As some other jobs are running on same slave.

Thanks In advance

Comment: If you cannot kill it from the UI, try restarting the jenkins service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop an unstoppable zombie job on Jenkins without restarting the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456592/how-to-stop-an-unstoppable-zombie-job-on-jenkins-without-restarting-the-server)