# How to abort a Jenkins Job programmatically at a specified time

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to abort my Jenkins Job before clock hits a particular time. I didn't find anything which stops it automatically at a specified time(I don't want to do it manually). Is there anything like that?

I have read this post, but none of the answer solves my problem [How to stop an unstoppable zombie job on Jenkins without restarting the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456592/how-to-stop-an-unstoppable-zombie-job-on-jenkins-without-restarting-the-server/29704511#29704511)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop a long running job, let's say, it is running more than 3 hours, then below jenkins plugins does exactly that for you.

[Abort a build if it is likely stuck](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin)

Or, if you want certain build to abort on a specific time (i.e, no build should run at 5 pm daily), then you can configure groovy script to do that.

Comment: Thanks @prudviraj for your answer. How can I go about configuring groovy script to abort a running job, lets say, at 8 pm?