# Stopping a python script running in linux from Jenkins

Tags: python, linux, jenkins

I have a script placed in the `linux` box with name test.py. I have triggered this script using Jenkins and the job is running successfully.

My query here is if i have to stop the script execution, how can i sent the signal to the script to stop from Jenkins itself? I tried stopping the job but that didnt stop the script execution.

Manually from the linux box, I have used the `try` and `except KeyboardInterrupt` and it's working. How can i do the same way from the Jenkins. Do i have to add any code to capture this when i stop the Jenkins job. Please clarify.

Sample script -

```
#!/app/code/Python/bin/python3
import time    
for t in range(0, 500):
        print ("hi")
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: why not just shut down jenkins completely?

Comment: how would shutting down jenkins help here? it would stop the execution of other jobs which are already running, right?!

Comment: ok if there are other jobs then try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456592/how-to-stop-an-unstoppable-zombie-job-on-jenkins-without-restarting-the-server

Comment: i dont think this will stop the execution of my python script which is running on the linux server. The idea here is to stop the python script which is present in the linux server similar to the way it was started using jenkins

Comment: do you want to stop it based on some condition using python script?

Comment: no condition as such, just stop it when the user wants to end the running script. the reason i am specifying Jenkins is because we give the Jenkins job to a end user and he can start/stop it based on his need.