# Job stuck after manual jobs deletion

Tags: jenkins

I performed a manual clean by deleting job folders directly into the filesystem, and now I find a stucked running job that I cannot abort.

I've tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456592/how-to-stop-an-unstoppable-zombie-job-on-jenkins-without-restarting-the-server/38481808#38481808) to force it to be stopped, but it doesn't work as it is not able to find the existing job in the system.

Additionally, when I click over the running job I get a 404 error:

```
"Problem accessing <route_to_job_that_doesnt_exist_anymore>"
Reason: Not found
```

Is there something I can do to abort this running job without restarting the server?

Answer (score 0):

A way to stop a build (Like actually aborting it) is by adding a `/stop` at the end of the job url, behind the Build Number.
Example: `http://myjenkins/project/123/stop`

If this doesn't work, there is also the "Hard Kill". Instead of adding `/stop` you add `/kill`. I guess you need Admin Access for that POST action.

Don't know though if it works for jobs that don't exist on the Jenkins Host anymore due to missing filesystems

Comment: Just tried and it seems that it doesn't work with missing filesystems :(