# could not stop maven build jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

We have some maven build jobs which was hanging, and I could not stop them. I also tried the console script to stop as this topic [How to stop an unstoppable zombie job on Jenkins without restarting the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456592/how-to-stop-an-unstoppable-zombie-job-on-jenkins-without-restarting-the-server), but no luck, it's return an error.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.finish() is applicable for argument types: (hudson.model.Result, java.io.IOException) values: [ABORTED, java.io.IOException: Aborting build]
Possible solutions: find(), findAll(), find(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
```

Is there something wrong or what might causing this issue? 
Jenkins version 2.190.1
Thanks